# Extract count of specific links from a web page.

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python script using BeautifulSoup. I need to scrape a website and count unique links ignoring the links starting with '#'.

Example if the following links exist on a webpage:

https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions

https://www.stackoverflow.com/foo

https://www.cnn.com/

For this example, the only two unique links will be (The link information after the main domain name is removed):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/    Count 2
https://cnn.com/              Count 1
```

Note: this is my first time using python and web scraping tools.

I appreciate all the help in advance.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")


count = 0

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function named [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) from `urllib.parse` which you can get `netloc` of urls. And there is a new awesome HTTP library named [`requests_html`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) which can help you get all links in source file.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from collections import Counter
from urllib.parse import urlparse

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("the link you want to crawl")
unique_netlocs = Counter(urlparse(link).netloc for link in r.html.absolute_links)
for link in unique_netlocs:
    print(link, unique_netlocs[link])
```

Comment: This worked but I just need to display the domain and the count for that domain. So for example if the links on the webpage our www.foo.com/bar, www.foo.com/bash, www.foo.com/bar. The output will be www.foo.com 3

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)").text, "html.parser")

foundUrls = Counter([link["href"] for link in soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and not href.startswith("#"))])
foundUrls = foundUrls.most_common()

for item in foundUrls:
    print ("%s: %d" % (item[0], item[1]))
```

The `soup.find_all` line checks if every `a`tag has an `href` set and if it doesn't start with the # character.
The Counter method counts the occurrences of each list entry and the `most_common` orders by the value.

The `for` loop just prints the results.

Comment: This worked but I just need to display the domain and the count for that domain. So for example if the links on the webpage our www.foo.com/bar, www.foo.com/bash, www.foo.com/bar. The output will be www.foo.com 3

Answer (score 0):

My way to do this is to find all links using beautiful soup and then determine which link redirects to which location:

```
def get_count_url(url): # get the umber of links having the same domain and suffix
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
count = 0
urls={} #dictionary for the domains
# input_domain=url.split('//')[1].split('/')[0]
#library to extract the exact domain( ex.- blog.bbc.com and bbc.com have the same domains )
input_domain=tldextract.extract(url).domain+"."+tldextract.extract(url).suffix 
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    word =link.get('href')
    # print(word)
    if word:
        # Same website or domain calls
        if "#" in word or word[0]=="/": #div call or same domain call
            if not input_domain in urls:
                # print(input_domain)
                urls[input_domain]=1 #if first encounter with the domain
            else:
                urls[input_domain]+=1 #multiple encounters
        elif "javascript" in word:
            # javascript function calls (for domains that use modern JS frameworks to display information)
            if not "JavascriptRenderingFunctionCall" in urls:
                urls["JavascriptRenderingFunctionCall"]=1
            else:
                urls["JavascriptRenderingFunctionCall"]+=1
        else:
            # main_domain=word.split('//')[1].split('/')[0]
            main_domain=tldextract.extract(word).domain+"." +tldextract.extract(word).suffix
            # print(main_domain)
            if main_domain.split('.')[0]=='www':
                main_domain = main_domain.replace("www.","") # removing the www
            if not main_domain in urls: # maintaining the dictionary
                urls[main_domain]=1
            else:
                urls[main_domain]+=1
        count += 1

for key, value in urls.items(): # printing the dictionary in a paragraph format for better readability
    print(key,value)
return count
```

tld extract finds the correct url name and soup.find_all('a') finds a tags. The if statements check for same domain redirect, javascript redirect or other domain redirects.